Contradiction between Chern connection on $TM^{(1,0)}$ and Levi-Civita connection on $T_\mathbb CM$ on a Kähler manifold
Let $M$ be a Kähler manifold with Levi-Civita connection $\nabla$ on $T_\mathbb CM$, then $\nabla$ is also the Chern connection on $TM^{(1,0)}$.
So if we write $\nabla=\nabla'+\nabla''$ for the decomposition corresponding to $A^{1}(TM^{(1,0)})=A^{1,0}(TM^{(1,0)}) \oplus A^{0,1}(TM^{(1,0)})$, then $\nabla''=\overline\partial$ by the definition of Chern connection. Equivalently, under any holomorphic frame of $TM^{(1,0)}$, each entry of the connection matrix $\theta$ is a $(1,0)$-form. This is also equivalent to the fact that for any holomorphic section $u$ of $TM^{(1,0)}$, $\nabla u$ is a $TM^{(1,0)}$-valued $(1,0)$-form.
Write $u=X-iJX$, where $X\in\Gamma(TM)$. Let $Y\in\Gamma(TM)$. Since $\nabla u$ is a $TM^{(1,0)}$-valued $(1,0)$-form and $Y+iJY$ is of type $(0,1)$, we have $\nabla_{Y+iJY}u=0$. But
\begin{align*}
0&=\nabla_{Y+iJY}u=\nabla_{Y+iJY}(X-iJX)\\
&=\nabla_YX-i\nabla_Y(JX)+i\nabla_{JY}X+\nabla_{JY}(JX)\\
(\text{since}~\nabla J=0)&=\nabla_YX-iJ\nabla_YX+i\nabla_{JY}X+J\nabla_{JY}X\\
&=\nabla_YX-iJ\nabla_YX+i(\nabla_X(JY)+[JY,X])+J(\nabla_X(JY)+[JY,X])\\
&=\nabla_YX-\nabla_XY+iJ(\nabla_XY-\nabla_YX)+i[JY,X]+J[JY,X]\\
&=[Y,X]+iJ[X,Y]+i[JY,X]+J[JY,X]\\
&=[Y,X]+J[JY,X]-iJ([Y,X]+J[JY,X]).
\end{align*}
Therefore
$$[Y,X]+J[JY,X]=0$$
which means $J[Y,X]=[JY,X]$. So $X$ is automorphic. This is obviously false since $X\in\Gamma(TM)$ is arbitrary. So where is the mistake in the above argument?
Thank you very much for your attention. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Is the mistake "$X\in\Gamma(TM)$ is arbitrary" at the end of the context?

Yes, $X$ is not arbitrary (while $Y$ is). In fact, you already clearly wrote what the key property is: "for any holomorphic section $u$ of $TM^{(1,0)}$, $\nabla u$ is a $TM^{(1,0)}$-valued $(1,0)$-form".
Now, if $u=X-iJX$, what does the condition "$u$ is a holomorphic section" translate to for $X$?
Let me know if you need other hints!

Thank you for your attention. For $X$, this means if we write$$X=u^i\frac\partial{\partial x^i}+v^i\frac\partial{\partial y^i},$$then $$\frac{\partial u^i}{\partial x^j}=\frac{\partial v^i}{\partial y^j},\quad\frac{\partial u^i}{\partial y^j}=-\frac{\partial v^i}{\partial x^j},$$where $\frac\partial{\partial y^i}=J\frac\partial{\partial x^i}$. At first, I simply thought $\forall~X\in\Gamma(TM)$, $X-iJX$ is a holomorphic section, but later on, I searched for relevant definitions then understood :)

And I apologize for not searching carefully at first.

@HeroZhang001 no problem! It was a good question to ask. cheers!
